# Camunda WebApp couldnt be started in SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, camunda

maybe somebody can help me with my problem. Currently trying to get Camunda running within my Spring Boot App. The Core Camunda Parts i could get running, but now i would like to add also the WebApps of Camunda (Cockpit / Tasklist etc.)

i added the dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
<artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp</artifactId>
<version>7.13.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
```

I tried to access it via the localhost:8080/camunda/app/welcome/ but besides of the Loading indicator i cant see anything. In my Spring Boot Application instead I see that a lot of Java Script couldn't be found from Frontend Request. e.g getting the error 404 /localhost/camunda/require.js not found.

Has anybody any idea what i am doing wrong. I tried it once with an empty Spring Boot Project and there it was working fine, but adding it to an existing project causes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

More information on your project (depenedency:tree) would be required to tell why. Most likely you have included incompatible versions. Clearing the browser cache or trying in a private window may also help.
You can always create a clean Spring Boot setup with compatible library / Spring Boot versions including engine, REST API, Web Apps (and possibly security, Camunda BPM assert) using https://start.camunda.com/.